# DRY in setting loading state in redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm going to bring a real case so that I can explain it better. I have a webapp that user can apply job, so I have a job reducer, the actions would be creating_job, created_job, fetching_job, fetched_job, fecthing_jobs, fetched_jobs, applying_job, appliled_job, faving_job, faved_job etc..

At first, I thought loading state is so easy I have initialState like so

```
const initialState = {
   loading: true
}
```

Then in created_job just set it to false. But this won't work for all case, I can't share one loading state for all. So, later on, I namespaced them and did this

```
const initialState = {    creating_job_loading: true,   
fetching_job_loading: true,    fecthing_jobs: true    //etc }
```

How do I make this more DRY? is there a middleware I can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

As a learner I like this approach. If I don't misunderstand, you want to hold a global loading state. So create a progress or loading state, then use a reducer like this:

```
const progressReducer = ( state = 0, action ) => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
    case INCREMENT_PROGRESS:
        return state + 1;
    case DECREMENT_PROGRESS:
        return Math.max( state - 1, 0 );
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

For each action, dispatch an increment, when the job done dispatch a decrement. So, until each job is done, you will have a progressing or loading state.